# Can we ignore scrubbing for selective DateTime fields, when using VerifyTests library?

Tags: c#, verify-tests

This question is about Verify testing library. It srubs date fields by default. [Here is the official link](https://Verify%20library%20srubs%20date%20fields%20by%20default.%20Here%20is%20the%20official%20link.%20It%20also%20provides%20a%20way%20to%20disable%20this%20behavior%20for%20a%20given%20object,%20by%20using%20DontScrubDateTimes()%20method.%20Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20disable%20the%20scrubbing%20behavior%20for%20only%20a%20selected%20date%20property%20in%20an%20object,%20and%20not%20for%20all%20dates%20available%20in%20that%20object?). It also provides [a way](https://Verify%20library%20srubs%20date%20fields%20by%20default.%20Here%20is%20the%20official%20link.%20It%20also%20provides%20a%20way%20to%20disable%20this%20behavior%20for%20a%20given%20object,%20by%20using%20DontScrubDateTimes()%20method.%20Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20disable%20the%20scrubbing%20behavior%20for%20only%20a%20selected%20date%20property%20in%20an%20object,%20and%20not%20for%20all%20dates%20available%20in%20that%20object?) to disable this behavior for a given object, by using `DontScrubDateTimes()` method. Is there a way to disable the scrubbing behavior for only a selected date property in an object, and not for all dates available in that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the library maintainer](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/discussions/804#discussioncomment-5214385), it is not supported.